# How to test if something is a function with Chai.should

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

I want to check if something is a function with Chai.should. So I did

```
typeof(barfoo).should.equals('function')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yG3PL/64/)

This results in

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to equal 'function'
    at Context.<anonymous> (:73:31)
```

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work, because if I simply do

```
typeof(barfoo)
```

I get a string `function`. Although I've solved this now with `instanceOf` but I really want to understand this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need extra parentheses

```
(typeof(barfoo)).should.equals('function')
```

Otherwise your expression is interpreted as

```
typeof ((barfoo).should.equals('function'))
```

as you can see, you are calling `.should` on `barfoo` instead of `typeof barfoo` and then get the type of final result and discard it.

This is because `typeof` it not a function, it is an unary operator[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typeof-operator) and have a lower precedence than Member Access operator (`.`) and Function Call[<sup>[2]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). So `typeof` is evaluated last in this expression.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but would just like to add the assertion can be made via `barfoo.should.be.a('function')`

Answer (score 36):

Here is how you can check if `barfoo` is a function:

```
barfoo.should.be.a('function');
```

Comment: It's not [documented](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_a)

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible to test with instanceOf:

```
barfoo.should.be.instanceOf(Function);
```